# Flask - Store values in memory between requests

Tags: python, ajax, rest, flask, python-requests

I have a Single page application - Angularjs on the front and flask on the backend which lets the user upload a file (xlsx, csv...) and then interactively analyze/query the file

Essentially the user loads the file into memory on first upload and then subsequent ajax calls will tap into this file in memory. Im not sure how to keep the file in memory between subsequent requests (ajax).

The `g` variable is erased after each request and if I understand right used to access values across a request (set usually by `before_request` and available all through the `views`

The request context is local to the request. I did manage to set the value on the current_app and then was able to access this in my subsequent ajax calls

```
# On my first file upload, i load the file into memory
and set it to a variable on current_app:

from flask import current_app
@app.route('/upload', methods =['POST'])
def upload():
   ...
   upload file into memory
   ...
   current_app.file = file_in_memory



@app.route('/subsequent_call')
def subsequent():
    # i'm able to access the file in memory through 
    the current_app.file which i set earlier

    return current_app.file.number_of_lines()
```

This method of storing the file in memory on the current_app just doesnt seem right and feels too dirty/hackish. Would this scale at all ?

I could pickle the file after every request and pull it back up on each request. But Storing/pickling and refetching the file every time into memory when a user is interactively querying the data seems too heavy/inefficient

Is there any other elegant/right way to do this, app_context, werkzeug locals etc ? Or am i thinking about it all wrong ?

Comment: Storing state on the web server is pretty bad practice. Why does it need to be in memory?

Comment: @Jharris: Agree abt the webserver storing state. The file needs to be in memory as i load it into a pandas object. pickling the pandas object between requests feels a little too inefficient.

Comment: For example, when you use explicit process pool. Of course I can store everything in a db, but it can be much more efficient working with memory for some specific cases.

Answer (score 3):

Storing file in this way is not going to work if your webserver is spawning multiple processes (workers) to handle requests, and that is how most production servers works.

Further to keep file object in memory is not going to scale if your server load increases, you can either save file in file system and initialize the pandas object during every requests. You can compare this with loading pickled object and see which is faster. You will also have to consider overhead of pickling not just unpickling.

EDIT: explanation of why it wont work in production

Gunicorn and similar webservers are likely to spawn multiple workers unless you are restricting in config, a worker is essentially a separate process and each process has its own python execution environment. So lets say your first request hits worker1 and you create a variable `current_app.file = file_in_memory`  in that process. Then your second request could hit worker2 which has its own python execution environment where your variable is not available because they are not shared across processes. In fact there might be a value in that variable but it belongs to different user request.

So all in all

1. It does not guarantee that same object is available across requests
2. It could get overridden by another user who is also simultaneously using your app

Comment: Thanks Shreyas. Im running a gunicorn server with Nginx as a reverse proxy. do you mind elaborating on why this is not going to work on a production server ?

Comment: Makes sense Shreyas. Thanks...One follow up question: im guessing if I use flask-cache instead of storing the variable on the current_app, i could overcome this issue. But any clue on how flask-cache routes the right request to the right worker ?

Comment: Yes you can overcome this if you use flask cache. But you will have to pickle it before storing in cache. Or I think flask will do that for you. And flask cache does not do any routing to worker. This works just across requests and across workers

Comment: looks like flask-cache pickles and unpickles it automatically if needed. ill upvote it but am hesitant to accept this as the answer, as im still looking for a solution which fits my needs. Not sure how to do this while still keeping the flask-app stateless - i guess it might not be possible and the only option is to pickle and unpickle it between requests...

Comment: I think so too that it is not possible. Can you try implementation with pickle? I think there won't be significant increase in delay. Use cpickle which is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Although I am answering the question very late, this would still help many of us. 
For sharing values between requests you should trust on using cache memory. Cache memory in flask is simple to implement using flask-cache and redis as database. It would be most efficient and reliable way of doing it. Read any article on implementation of redis as cache db in flask for further reference.

Comment: Flask-Cache's simple cache strategy is not thread safe. You will need to use an external server one way or another it seems.