# LDA gensim model in a flask HTTP API - Memory issues

Tags: http, flask, out-of-memory, gensim, lda

I am new to Machine Learning and it is the first time that I am using python's gensim in order to extract topics from text.

I successfully trained a model (for 100 topics) and then I had the idea to use that model in an HTTP API that I created using python flask. The endpoint gives as back terms for a given text.

Btw model is loaded when I initialize the API.

After trying this out on production, memory (on a small VM ~ 1GB Ram) exhausted and finally I got an error:

```
tags = tags + lda.topic_words(topic_index, num_of_keywords_for_topic, model, words)
  File "/var/app/tagbee/lda.py", line 64, in topic_words
    x2 = model.get_topic_terms(topicid=topic_index, topn=number_of_keywords)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gensim/models/ldamodel.py", line 1224, in get_topic_terms
    topic = self.get_topics()[topicid]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gensim/models/ldamodel.py", line 1204, in get_topics
    topics = self.state.get_lambda()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gensim/models/ldamodel.py", line 269, in get_lambda
    return self.eta + self.sstats
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 96.6 MiB for an array with shape (100, 253252) and data type float32
```

So I have some questions:

- Can a gensim LDA model be used that way, mean in an HTTP API?
- If yes, what is the trick to make it happen? If it needs at least 90MB of memory per request, how does it scale?
- Is there any alternative approach?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask - Store values in memory between requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31407593/flask-store-values-in-memory-between-requests)

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be related to LDA or `gensim` only accidentally. The main point seems to be how to and maintain (and reuse) an object in memory across a number of `Flask` requests.

Inspired by [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/appcontext/#storing-data) and answers from this question:
[Flask - Store values in memory between requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31407593/flask-store-values-in-memory-between-requests) I propose the following approach:

```
from flask import g # global context of all queries

def get_lda_model():
    if 'lda' not in g:
        g.lda = # read a model file here

    return g.lda

@app.route('/example_request_path', methods =['POST'])
def my_request():
    lda = get_lda_model()
    # use lda model here....
```

Once the LDA model is loaded you can reuse it very quickly in a number of requests without reloading it into memory. As long as your model is not going to be changed across requests it does not matter if this approach is thread-safe.